# Getting Error while performing Undersampling for Sklearn

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying built an randomforest classifier  for binary classification . My  data is inbalanced hence I am performing  undersampling.

```
train = data.drop(['Co_Name','Cust_ID','Phone','Shpr_ID','Resi_Cnt','Buz_Cnt','Nearby_Cnt','parseNumber','removeString','Qty','bins','Adj_Addr','Resi','Weight','Resi_Area','Lat','Lng'], axis=1)
Y = data['Resi']
from sklearn import metrics
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
X_train_res, y_train_res = rus.fit_sample(train, Y)
```

**I am getting the below error**

```
446         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
    447         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
--> 448             array = array.astype(np.float64)
    449         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    450             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the dataframe? or a sample of that!

This error can be a lot of things, for example:

- If you try:

  np.asarray(
      [
          [1, 2], 
          [2, 3, 4]
      ], 
      dtype=np.float)

You will get:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This is because the array have incorrect shape of columns. So you can't create an array from lists, with a column length different on the second list. So doesn't match column length.

But your error probably it's related to train vs Y shape or the type in the train(data). During the Under-sampled fit function should have some conversion that throws this error. Confirm if train (data) have the appropriate **type** before to do the RandomUnderSampler.